# USing Openssl to find PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 in Android

Tags: android, sqlcipher

I am also using sqlCipher in my application. They use openssl for calculating PKDF2 and I have read somewhere that openssl implementation is very faster than java implementation to find PKDF2. So my question is:

- Is this true that openssl can give me better performace on android?
- Can I use openssl implementation used in sqlCipher?
- If yes how can I use find PKDF2 using openssl?
- If No then how can I use openssl to find PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 in
  android. I have searched over the net but didn't found any example.

Thanks Nick for your suggestion

I have tried your suggestion and I am able to call c function using JNI in my java class.
Now I have one problem. How should I include openssl (Or call PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1 in my c code). Here is my code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define KEY_LEN      32
#define KEK_KEY_LEN  20
#define ITERATION     1

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_testjni_MainActivity_someFunction(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj) {
//  return 3;

    size_t i;
            unsigned char *out;
            const char pwd[] = "password";
            unsigned char salt_value[] = {'s','a','l','t'};

            out = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * KEK_KEY_LEN);

            printf("pass: %s\n", pwd);
            printf("ITERATION: %u\n", ITERATION);
            printf("salt: "); for(i=0;i<sizeof(salt_value);i++) { printf("%02x", salt_value[i]); } printf("\n");

            if( PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(pwd, strlen(pwd), salt_value, sizeof(salt_value), ITERATION, KEK_KEY_LEN, out) != 0 )
            {
                    printf("out: "); for(i=0;i<KEK_KEY_LEN;i++) { printf("%02x", out[i]); } printf("\n");
            }
            else
            {
                    fprintf(stderr, "PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1 failed\n");
            }
return "";
}
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := example
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := example.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I am getting this error when I compile my c code using ndk-build:

C:/Users/Nauman/Downloads/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/p
rebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-
linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/example/example.o: in fun
ction Java_com_example_testjni_MainActivity_someFunction:jni/example.c:25: error
: undefined reference to 'PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libexample.so] Error 1

**EDIT**

Here is the exception I get when loading libs:

07-22 10:04:26.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-156
07-22 10:04:26.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load stlport_shared from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ebricks.cii-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.ebricks.cii-1, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
07-22 10:04:26.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:355)
07-22 10:04:26.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:525)
07-22 10:04:26.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:112)
07-22 10:04:26.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:107)

Answer (score 0):

SQLCipher for Android does statically link OpenSSL, so `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1` is included within the precompiled binaries.  However if all you need is a call `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1` directly, libcrypto.so is generally distributed with all Android platforms, however the version is often different on many platforms.  To access `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1`, you will need to write a JNI interop library with the Android NDK that links to libcrypto, along with a Java wrapper class to load your native library and make the call into JNI.  As a reference, I statically link OpenSSL within SQLCipher for Android [here](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/blob/master/external/Android.mk).

Comment: Hi Nick, I have edited my question please let me knw how to include openssl in my c code?

Comment: You will need to either statically or dynamically link OpenSSL in order for the linker to complete the build.

Comment: I am stuck with this thing for 5 days. I have tried building static library. I am not able to get it. Can you please let me know the steps how can I integrate simple static library and compute PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1?

Comment: Or how can I use pre-complied binaries or libcrypto.so provided by android platform directly?

Comment: Nick I have used static library to build native code and it works fine in sperate project. But when I add that project to my project which contain sqlcipher It crashes when this command runs. SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this); I think there is come conflict between sqlciper openssl and mine, how can i remvoe this issue? Please help me in this regard.

Comment: I have also paste the exception above.